# How do I parse or print data after matching a particular line in Perl?

Tags: perl

i have file with dat as below

```
      extern const
      extern const

     /*****************************************************************************
      *                Data                                         *
      *****************************************************************************/
     #ifdef SELECTED
     /*****************************************************************************
      *                  comments                                         *
      *****************************************************************************/

      int test_data1_value;
      int test_data2_value;
      int test_data3_value;
      int test_data4_value;


     #endif
      random data
      random data

    /**********************************************************************
    *                       definitions                     *
    **********************************************************************/
    #define
    #define
```

i need to extract the data line starting with "uint8" between to comments "test data buffer" and "receive signal definations"
how can this be done i have written a script like

```
   while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   if (/^\*\s* Data / ... /^\*\s*definitions/) {
    if (m/^\s*int/) {
       print "$_";

         }
      }
     }
```

i need out put to be as

```
      int test_data1_value;
      int test_data2_value;
      int test_data3_value;
      int test_data4_value;
```

after matching particular comment string it should check for line starting with int and print that whole line . if there is no int at the beginning of line it should exclude that particular line . but this code is not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what you want to do with those data between `#ifdef` and `#endif`, but looks like how to filter those data is your main problem, so here is how to do it by using [operator `...`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators), which can be used to indicate a line range, exactly what we need:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^\s*\*\s*test Data Buffer/ ... /^\s*\*\s*Receive signal definitions/) {
        if (m/^\s*uint8/) {
            print "$_\n";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
      random data

     #ifdef CAN_CH0_SELECTED
     /*****************************************************************************
      *                  test Data Buffer                                         *
      *****************************************************************************/
      uint8 test_data1_value;
      uint8 test_data2_value;
      uint8 test_data3_value;
      uint8 test_data4_value;


     #endif
      random data
      random data

     /*****************************************************************************
      *                  test Data Buffer                                         *
      *****************************************************************************/
```

Comment: hi
am trying to extract the data between #ifdef and #endif and remove #define from that string and save it to a file.
am unable to get the data using this script can u help me?
thank you in advance

Comment: @Naidu What do you mean you are "unable to get the data using this script"? Running it will output and only output those four lines beginning with `#define` in your sample input.

Comment: sorry actually i have mor than 2 #ifdef and #endif in my file but still am unable to print any data to the file at least as per the script it should print data in some range right ?
@Lee

Comment: @Naidu This script works for more than one `#ifdef ... #endif` pair case. If it does not work for you, please update your question to include **your actual script and input data**, so I can figure out where is the problem.

Comment: i have made some changes to the question please do check them i think it may make bit clear for you that what am i looking for
thank you

Comment: @Naidu After fixed the problem in `print @test[2]"\n";` (changed it to `print "$test[2]\n";`), your script will output four `value;`. Is this what you expected? By the way, you should ALWAYS include `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of your Perl scripts, this will save you LOTS of time.

Comment: @ lee hi i still have problem extracting data between those two strings from the file if u dont mind can u make it clear for me

Comment: @Naidu Does the script in my updated answer solve your problem?

Comment: hi @lee what if i take limits as test Data Buffer which is in comments and extract the data and take the whole string as out put is this correct i have edited the code little bit once can u have a look at it

Comment: i need to print the data jus after the matched pattern am unable to get it i have been struggling since long time can u help me

Comment: @Naidu Please take some time to work out a final question, state clearly in it what you want to achieve, give some examples, and include your problematic code and your expected output. Please DO NOT change your question continually.

Comment: @Naidu Oh, please watch out your spelling and syntax. I am not a native English speaker, it is very difficult for me to decipher those incorrect statements.

Comment: i will make my question clear and make necessary changes to the question ju 2 mins @lee sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Naidu Answer updated. Final answer to the final question :-)